# How to sort a text file with three columns, each separated by a comma?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I have a text file as such,

```
1151,1000,801;
1152,3000,801;
1154,1000,801;
1156,3000,170;
```

I'd like to sort based on the third number in each row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following command to achieve the task,

```
sort -k 3 --field-separator=","
```

Comment: Could explain what the command does? Also don't forget to accept your own answer.

Comment: For sorting plain numbers use the `-n`, in longhand: `sort --numeric-sort -f ',' -k 3`